# Git forked branch not pulled commits from upstream master branch

Tags: git

I have a forked branch and I have updated it by pulling the changes from the upstream / remote master branch. However when I create a pull request for the work to back in the (upstream) master branch it is doesn’t appear to have pulled all the changes in.

Running a pull again thinks that the branch is up to date.

The missing changes are not ones of merge conflicts which I was starting to suspect may be the cause.

I’m using VS Code on Windows, Git for Windows and also got GitLens installed.

What commands can I run to either detect the missing commits or apply them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you pushed your changes (after pulling)? Otherwise you will only have pulled locally. Pull requests are always created from the remote repository and you need to tell the remote which commits exist in a branch. When you pull, the remote is unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be pulling from the wrong remote.

Check which remote repositories you have with this command:

```
git remote -v
```

Ideally, you should have two remotes, one with the link to your fork (typically `origin`),
and one with the link to the upstream repository (typically `upstream`).

If you are missing `upstream`, you can add it with

```
git remote add upstream <url>
```

Now you should be able to pull from upstream with

```
git pull upstream master
```

and update your remote fork with

```
git push origin
```

---

I've made a few assumptions here, so feel free to comment if it doesn't work for you.